# How to check if bean property exist win BeanUtils or similar?

Tags: java, javabeans, apache-commons-beanutils

Is there ready made routine to check if bean has getter for specific property name given by string?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You could do this, from [BeanUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/apidocs/org/apache/commons/beanutils/PropertyUtils.html#isReadable%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String%29):

```
static boolean propertyExists (Object bean, String property) {
    return PropertyUtils.isReadable(bean, property) && 
           PropertyUtils.isWriteable(bean, property); 
}
```

As far as I know there isn't a one-liner that encapsulates both of those, since readability / writeability are independent.

If you're only interested in the getter, `PropertyUtils.isReadable()` alone will work.